# Defaults utility: how to get xcode project info

Tags: command-line, defaults

I have found that utility `defaults` can get info from .plist file.
But how can I canonically pass as parameter to it `path to .plist file` ?

I read about `<domain>` parameter but still don't have enough understanding of it.
If I go to project directory where .plist file of projects is placed and input command

`> defaults read ./Project.plist`

I will see error that this domain

Domain `./Project.plist` is not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that the `domain` parameter is a full path to a file with .plist extension

So, the correct way to pass parameter `domain` which points to specific project is this:

`> defaults read ~/FULLPATHTOPROJECT/Project.plist`

But I will glad to see your answers of defaults-utility best practices

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot of information about this in the man page for `defaults` (just run `man defaults` in Terminal):

```
 Specifying domains:

 domain    If no flag is specified, domain is a domain name of the form com.companyname.appname.  Example:

                 defaults read com.apple.TextEdit

 -app application
           The name of an application may be provided instead of a domain using the -app flag. Example:

                 defaults read -app TextEdit

 filepath  Domains may also be specified as a path to an arbitrary plist file, with or without the '.plist' exten-
           sion. For example:

                 defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist

           normally gives the same result as the two previous examples.  In the following example:

                 defaults write ~/Desktop/TestFile foo bar

           will write the key 'foo' with the value 'bar' into the plist file 'TestFile.plist' that is on the
           user's desktop. If the file does not exist, it will be created. If it does exist, the key-value pair
           will be added, overwriting the value of 'foo' if it already existed.

           WARNING: The defaults command will be changed in an upcoming major release to only operate on prefer-
           ences domains. General plist manipulation utilities will be folded into a different command-line pro-
           gram.
```